# Only the First Button works in Django loop

Tags: javascript, html, django, for-loop, django-templates

The div only appears if the first button is clicked. Its works as i wanted but only for the first button in loop. When i manually put display = "block" it appears though on bith loop. What i want is to toggle the class "bg-model" by clicking on the class "editTime".

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance...

**HTML**

```
<h4>Appointments</h4>
                    {% if upcomming_appointments %}
                        {% for d in upcomming_appointments %}
                        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center flex-wrap">
                            <h6 class="mb-0">
                                <ion-icon name="medkit"></ion-icon> Appointment with <strong>{{d.PatientName}}</strong><a class="btn btn-info "
                                    id="sessionBtn" href="{% url 'medicalReport' d.id %}">Start Session</a>
                            </h6>
                            <span class="text-secondary">
                                Date: <strong>{{d.appoitmentDate}}</strong> <br>
                                Time: <strong>{{d.appoitmentTime}}</strong><br>
                                Symptoms: <strong>{{d.symptoms}}</strong><br>
                                Comment: <strong>{{d.Comments}}</strong><br>
                            </span>
                            <a id = "changeTime" class="editTime">Change time</a>
                            <a class="btn btn-info " id="logoutBtn" href="{% url 'delete_appointment' d.id %}"
                                onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel this appointment? This action is irreversible.')">Cancel
                                Appoitment</a>
                            <div class="bg-modal">
                                <div class="modal-contents">
                                    <div class="close">+</div>
                                    <form method="POST">
                                        <h5>Change Appointment Time</h5>
                                        {{d.id}}
                                        <input type="hidden" name="SessionID" value="{{d.id}}">
                                        <input type="time" id="timeChange" class="input" placeholder="Time">
                                        <button type="submit" class="loginBtn">Submit</button>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
```

**JS**

```
document.querySelector('.editTime').addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = "flex";
});

document.querySelector('.close').addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = "none";
});
```

**views.py**

```
def doctorProfile(request):
    upcomming_appointments = Appoitment.objects.all().filter(
        DoctorEmail=request.user, appoitmentDate__gte=timezone.now()).order_by('appoitmentDate')
    past_appointments = Appoitment.objects.all().filter(
        DoctorEmail=request.user, appoitmentDate__lt=timezone.now()).order_by('-appoitmentDate')
    g = request.user.groups.all()[0].name
    if g == 'Doctor':
        doctor_details = Doctor.objects.all().filter(EmailAddress=request.user)
        d = {'doctor_details': doctor_details,
             'upcomming_appointments': upcomming_appointments,
             'past_appointments': past_appointments}
    return render(request, 'doctorProfile.html', d)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue with your template. This is happening because HTML ids are strictly unique and since you are looping through, the id "changetime" is getting duplicated and thus only the first button is working.

The workaround through this is that first, you make the IDs unique by adding a variable, it could be like- id="changeTime_{{d.id}}" or you can completely remove the ID if it isn't being used anywhere. Secondly, you add onClick handler to the  tag.

You can do as follows:

```
<a href id="your_id" class="editTime" onclick="showModal()">
```

in your js file:

```
function showModal() {
    document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = "flex";
}
```

**EDIT:**

**Make sure to put your modal outside the for loop**

Since you want to also update the fields of the modal, you will have to use it via javascript.
Change your modal as follows:

```
 <div class="bg-modal">
                                <div class="modal-contents">
                                    <div class="close">+</div>
                                    <form method="POST">
                                        <h5>Change Appointment Time</h5>
                                        <span id="appId"></span>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="SessionID" value="">
                                        <input type="time" id="timeChange" class="input" placeholder="Time">
                                        <button type="submit" class="loginBtn">Submit</button>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

change on click functionality:

**html**

```
<a href id="your_id" class="editTime" onclick="showModal('{{d.id}}')">
```

**JavaScript**

```
function showModal(appointmentId) {
    document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = "flex";
    document.getElementByName('SessionID')[0].value = appointmentId;
    document.getElementById('appId').textContent = appointmentId;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this one before. The second or third button works but it shows the first .bg-modal only

Comment: Oh okay, I get it. You want to update that modal field's also, right?

Comment: @DarshanBuddhacharya this should help you out. It should dynamically update your modals fields. And also put the modal **OUTSIDE** the for loop.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. I have found a similar question in stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33643239/accessing-an-element-in-django-for-loop. I have tried it and it works.